# Solution verification of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ convergent, what can be said about $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, infinite-product

> Assume that the products $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$
> with positive factors both converge. Study the convergence of
> convergence of:
>
> (a) $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$;
>
> (b) $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nb_n$.

My textbook solves these by looking at $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(a_n^2)$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(a_nb_n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{a_n}{b_n}$, I tried a different strategy and I would like to ask to you for confirmation or helping me find mistakes.

My solution for (a): since
$$\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n^2=(a_1\cdot a_1)\cdot(a_2 \cdot a_2)\cdot...\cdot(a_k\cdot a_k)=(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot...\cdot a_k)\cdot(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_k)=\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)=\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)^2$$
Taking the limit as $k \to \infty$ both sides and using the continuity of the square power it is
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2=\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n^2=\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)^2=\left(\lim_{k \to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)^2$$
But by hypothesis $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, hence $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=l\in[0,\infty)$ and so
$$\left(\lim_{k \to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)^2=l^2$$
Hence the product converges to $l^2$.

My solution for (b): since
$$\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n b_n=(a_1\cdot b_1)\cdot(a_2 \cdot b_2)\cdot...\cdot(a_k\cdot b_k)=(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot...\cdot a_k)\cdot(b_1\cdot b_2 \cdot ... \cdot b_k)=\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} b_n\right)$$
Taking the limit as $k \to \infty$ both sides and using the theorem "limit of product is product of limits when they converges", it is
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n b_n=\lim_{k\to\infty} \left[\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k} b_n\right)\right]=\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} b_n\right)$$
But by hypothesis $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges, hence $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=l\in[0,\infty)$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n=m \in [0,\infty)$; so
$$\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} b_n\right)=lm$$
Hence the product converges to $lm$.

Are these solutions correct?

Comment: That is completely correct.

Comment: Usually an infinite product is said to converge if the partial products converge to a **non-zero** number. So you should take $l,m \in (0,\infty)$ rather than $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the help. @KaviRamaMurthy this is very helpful, indeed the next exercise is about $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ and I thought I couldn't use the strategy used in this question because of the case where $l=0$ and $m=0$, so now according to what you say, can I extend what I did in (c) for $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ writing $\prod_{n=1}^k \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\prod_{n=1}^k a_n}{\prod_{n=1}^k b_n}$ and using the limit of ratio when both numerator and denominator don't tend to $0$, so $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{l}{m}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  @Gwyn